# Spring OAuth 2 + Spring Data Neo4j multi-tenancy

Tags: spring, spring-security, multi-tenant, oauth-2.0, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm going to implement multi-tenancy support in my Spring OAuth 2 + Spring Data Neo4j project.

I have configure my OAuth2 Authorization Server with a few different clients with a different `clientId`.

Also, I have added a base `TenantEntity` to my Spring Data Neo4j models:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class TenantEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String tenantId;

    public String getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

}
```

All of my existing Spring Data Neo4j entities must now extend this `TenantEntity`.

Right now I'm going to rewrite all of my Neo4j queries in order to support this `tenantId` parameter.

For example current query:

`MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND NOT (c)<-[:CONTAINS]-(:CriterionGroup) RETURN c`

I going to rewrite to following:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND d.tenantId = {tenantId} AND c.tenantId = {tenantId} AND NOT (c)<-[:CONTAINS]-(:CriterionGroup) RETURN c
```

In turn for `tenantId` I'm going to use OAuth2 `clientId` and store it together with every Neo4j entity.

Is it a correct approach in order to implement multi-tenancy or Spring OAuth2/Data Neo4j can propose something more standard for this purpose out of the box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Neo4j currently has no feature to support multi-tenancy, if you particularly need this, it must be worked-around as you have done. You solution looks reasonable.

Alternatively, licensing is by machine, so it is possible to use, for example, Docker and spin up multiple Neo4j instances each on a different port.